# while searching for unique id it is giving multiple count

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have 5 million documents which have unique customerid as mapping id for every document. While searching for unique customer it is returning 1992 documents. And this is happening for every unique id, giving difference count as It is supposed to give one document only.

I have executed below query in kibana:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{ 
  "query": {
     "match": {
      "customerid": "e32e6b34-5e3f-4bb9-a3af-e89714b418ca"
      }
  }
}
```

It is giving me below result for unique customer id:

```
{
 "took" : 20,
 "timed_out" : false,
 "_shards" : {
 "total" : 1,
 "successful" : 1,
 "skipped" : 0,
 "failed" : 0
            },
 "hits" : {
 "total" : {
 "value" : 1992,
 "relation" : "eq"
    },
 "max_score" : 59.505646,
 "hits" : [
 ....
 ....
 ....
```

Below is mapping of my index:

```
{
 "pb_2409" : {
 "mappings" : {
  "dynamic_date_formats" : [
    "yyyy-MM-dd||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
  ],
  "dynamic_templates" : [
    {
      "objects" : {
        "match_mapping_type" : "object",
        "mapping" : {
          "type" : "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "properties" : {
    "customerid" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What's the type of **customerid**?

Comment: Its text type. Also, I have updated the mapping of customerid above. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **customerid** type to **keyword** and add a **normalizer** to your index settings.

```
 "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_custom_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Than add a `"normalizer": "my_custom_normalizer"` to **customerid** field (in case you want to search your id incasesensitive)

```
"properties" : {
    "customerid" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256,
          "normalizer": "my_custom_normalizer"
        }
      }
}
```

Your search query will look like

```
    GET /my_index/_search
    { 
      "query": {
         "term": {
          "customerid.keyword": {
             "value":"e32e6b34-5e3f-4bb9-a3af-e89714b418ca"
          }
         }
      }
    }
```

Your new mappings:

```
PUT /index
{
  "pb_2409": {
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic_date_formats": [
        "yyyy-MM-dd||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      ],
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "objects": {
            "match_mapping_type": "object",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "nested"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "customerid": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "normalizer": "my_custom_normalizer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "normalizer": {
          "my_custom_normalizer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings
Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Assael, working with keyword search without adding normalizer. The only problem is I have 700-800 columns and around 400-450 or more columns are searchable. For every field it would be difficult to add normalizer to very field. That's why I have used dynamic mapping.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, My every unique id is GUID id, how can I search with case-sensitive. Correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: If you use **keyword** type and you indexed **customerid** with id **e32e6b34-5e3f-4bb9-a3af-e89714b418ca** then without a **normalizer** you will have to search it exactly as you indexed it to elasticsearch (meaning **e32e6b34-5e3f-4bb9-a3af-e89714b418ca** and not **E32E6B34-5E3F-4BB9-A3AF-E89714B418CA**  . To sum up - Keyword fields are only searchable by their exact value